# autonumeric clear button bugs

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an issue with the `<input>` that use autonumeric function. When cursor is move at the input text field, the value re-appear even after i have clicked on the clear search button. And the input value seems cannot parse value that more than 1,000,000.

```
    $(function(){
        if($('form input[type="text"][name*="_format"]').length){
             new AutoNumeric.multiple('form input[type="text"][name*="_comma"]', {
                  vMax: '9999999',
                  vMin: '0.01',
                  unformatOnSubmit: true,
                  modifyValueOnWheel: false,
                  decimalPlaces: 0,
              });
          }
   });
```

Comment: How can you use `AutoNumeric` method? From what extension/plugin? Add more detail, please...

Comment: its a standalone javascript lib, here is an url for more details http://autonumeric.org/